# Play multiple audio files with howlerjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, howler.js

I am trying to play with multiple audio files in a sequence without delay and I tried below code which is not working. In actual scenario I only need to have one button which will be play & turn Pause once audio is played and vise versa

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PWrYKw

```
<button id='play-button'> Play</button>
<button id='pause-button'>Pause</button>
<button id='preset-changer'>Present</button>

(function( $ ) {
'use strict';

jQuery(window).load(function() {
    var sound_files = {
            sound1 : new Howl({
                src: ['http://download.quranicaudio.com/verses/Sudais/mp3/001001.mp3'],
                loop: true
            }),
            sound2 : new Howl({
                src: ['http://download.quranicaudio.com/verses/Sudais/mp3/001002.mp3'],
                loop: true
            }),
            sound3 : new Howl({
                src: ['http://download.quranicaudio.com/verses/Sudais/mp3/001003.mp3'],
                loop: true
            })
        };

    var play_button = $('#play-button'),
        pause_button = $('#pause-button'),
        shift_preset = $('#preset-changer');

    play_button.click(function() {
        //sound_files.play();
          for (var prop in sound_files) {
            if(!sound_files.hasOwnProperty(prop)) continue;
            {sound_files[prop].play();}
          }
        });     

    //});
});

})(jQuery);
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong as I don't see any error messages.

Comment: You can also join your audio samples into one and control it using sprites. Check this [Cross Browser JS-CSS-MP3 Piano Keyboard Git](https://github.com/sanxofon/Cross-Browser-JS-CSS-MP3-Piano-Keyboard) for a simple example on how to do it. Check the [live demo](https://sanxofon.github.io/Cross-Browser-JS-CSS-MP3-Piano-Keyboard/) to see it in action.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
play_button.click(function() {
    sound_files.map(function(s) {
        s.play();
    })
});
```

Comment: No even this dont play anything

Answer (score 0):

You are not correctly referring to the `howler.js` file in your CodePen demo. Change it with this—`https://rawgit.com/goldfire/howler.js/master/dist/howler.js`.

Another thing, `.load()` was deprecated long back. Change that line with `.on('load', fn)` like so:

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
    ...
});
```

It works with the above changes.

**EDIT #1**: You need to make use of the events the `Howler` objects give you to properly sequence the tracks. Here's how I did it though I think it could be a lot cleaner with more state variables especially since you want to incorporate pausing and resuming:

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
  var isPlaying = false;
  var sound_files = [new Howl({
      src: ['http://download.quranicaudio.com/verses/Sudais/mp3/001001.mp3'],
      loop: false
    }),
    new Howl({
      src: ['http://download.quranicaudio.com/verses/Sudais/mp3/001002.mp3'],
      loop: false
    }),
    new Howl({
      src: ['http://download.quranicaudio.com/verses/Sudais/mp3/001003.mp3'],
      loop: false
    })

  ];

  var play_button = $('#play-button'),
    pause_button = $('#pause-button'),
    shift_preset = $('#preset-changer');

  for (var i = 0; i < sound_files.length - 1; ++i) {
    sound_files[i].on('end',
      (function(i) {
        return function() {
          sound_files[i + 1].play();
        }
      }(i))
    );
  }
  sound_files[i].on('end', function() {
    isPlaying = false;
  })

  play_button.click(function() {
    if (!isPlaying) {
      isPlaying = true;
      sound_files[0].play();
    }
  });

  function playTrack(index) {
    console.log("playing " + index);
    sound_files[index].play();
    sound_files[index].once('end', function() {
      if (index < sound_files.length - 1)
        playTrack(index + 1);
      else
        isPlaying = false;
    });
  }

  //});
});
```

Comment: @SimK Could you replace your JS code with the one given above and see if that helps? I basically looped through each `Howler` object and added a handler to every object except the last one to play the next track.